# Does encoding affect the result of strstr() (and related functions)

Tags: c++, c

Does character set encoding affects the result of strstr() function?

For example, I have read a data to "buf" and do this:

```
char *p = strstr (buf, "UNB");
```

I wonder whether the data is encoded in ASCII or others (e.g. EBCDIC) affects the result of this function?
(Since "UNB" are different bit streams under different encoding ways...)

If yes, what's the default that is used for these function? (ASCII?)

Thanks!

Comment: If the character encoding of your input data doesn't match your "native" encoding, then the above may indeed not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C functions like `strstr` operate on the raw `char` data,
independently of the encoding.  In this case, you potentially have two
different encodings: the one the compiler used for the string literal,
and the one your program used when filling `buf`.  If these aren't the
same, then the function may not work as expected.

With regards to the "default" encoding, there isn't one, at least as far
as the standard is concerned; the ”basic execution character
set“ is implementation defined.  In practice, systems which don't
use an encoding derived from ASCII (ISO 8859-1 seems the most common, at
least here in Europe) are exceedingly rare.  As for the encoding you get
in `buf`, that depends on where the characters come from; if you're
reading from an `istream`, it depends on the locale `imbue`d in the
stream.  In practice, however, again, almost all of these (UTF-8,
ISO8859-x, etc.) are derived from ASCII, and are identical with ASCII
for all of the characters in the **basic** execution character set
(which includes all of the characters legal in traditional C).  So for
`"UNB"`, you're likely safe.  (but for something like `"üéâ"`, you almost
certainly aren't.)

Comment: Hi James, data read to buf is directly from network partner and their data is encoded in EBCDIC. So if I wanna do strstr with buf and "UNB", I should convert "UNB" form ASCII to its corresponding EBCDIC value string "U+B". Is this correct?

Comment: I'd favor converting the data when it is read, and sticking to ASCII-related encodings internally.  In theory, it should be possible to imbue an EBCDIC locale in the input stream, and let it take care of everything.  In practice, not many implementations come with an EBCDIC locale, and while it's not that difficult to define a new `codecvt` facet (the part of the locale which does the encoding), depending on how you're reading, other solutions might be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Your string constant ("UNB") is encoded in source file encoding, so it must match the encoding of your buffer

Answer (score 1):

Both string parameters must be the same encoding. With string literals the encoding of the C++ source (platform encoding). For Unicode, UTF-8 the function has another problem: Unicode has accented letters with diacritics but these can also be encoded as basic letter plus a combining diacritic symbol. **é** can be one letter **[é]** or two: **[e]** + **[combining-´]**. Normalisation exists.

For Java it is becoming usance (a very silent development) to explicitly set the source encoding to UTF-8. For C++ projects I am not aware of such conventions becoming widespread.

Answer (score 0):

`strstr` should work without a problem on UTF-8 encoded unicode characters.

Answer (score -1):

with this function, data is encoded in ASCII.