# Is it safe to use `strstr` to search for multibyte UTF-8 characters in a string?

Tags: c, string, utf-8, multibyte-functions

Following my previous question: [Why `strchr` seems to work with multibyte characters, despite man page disclaimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25566356/3194340), I figured out that `strchr` was a bad choice.

Instead I am thinking about using `strstr` to look for a single character (multi-byte not `char`):

```
const char str[] = "This string contains é which is a multi-byte character";
char * pos = strstr(str, "é"); // 'é' = 0xC3A9: 2 bytes 
printf("%s\n", pos);
```

Ouput:

> é which is a multi-byte character

Which is what I expect: the position of the 1st byte of my multi-byte character.

A priori, this is not the canonical use of `strstr` but it seems to work well.
Is this workaround safe ? Can you think about any side-effect or special case that would cause a bug ?

**[EDIT]:** I should precise that I do not want to use `wchar_t` type and that strings I handle are UTF-8 encoded (I am aware this [choice](http://utf8everywhere.org/) can be discussed but this an irrelevant debate)

Comment: _"A priori, this is not the canonical"_ Isn't it? It's just a UTF8 encoded string.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it doesn't have to be UTF8.

Comment: It depends, how "normal" your implementation is. The locale-specific multibyte encoding could be UTF-7 (or anything else having state), in which case `strstr` may yield false positives.

Comment: I should ask. Why not use proper UTF-8 functions instead of?

Comment: @Jack If you are talking about `wchar` I got the same question in my previous post ^^ : see [why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566356/why-strchr-seems-to-work-with-multibyte-characters-despite-man-page-disclaime#comment39933408_25566356)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does encoding affect the result of strstr() (and related functions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209466/does-encoding-affect-the-result-of-strstr-and-related-functions)

Comment: The aspect of UTF-8 should be in the post title and tag as it is a key point in the post.

Comment: check [C's strstr function, for instance, will work perfectly as long as both its inputs are valid, null-terminated UTF-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313596/5407848)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### With UTF-8

UTF-8 is designed in such a way that it is immune to partial mismatch of character as shown above and cause any false positive. **So it is completely safe to use `strstr` with UTF-8 coded multibyte characters.**

#### When used with other encodings

`strstr` is not suitable for strings containing multi-byte characters.

If you are searching for a string that doesn't contain multi-byte character inside a string that contains multi-byte character, it may give false positive. (While using [shift-jis encoding](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/docs/misc/kanji-sjis.html) in japanese locale, strstr("掘something", "@some") may give false positive)

```
+---------+----+----+----+
|   c1    | c2 | c3 | c4 |  <--- string
+---------+----+----+----+

     +----+----+----+
     | c5 | c2 | c3 |  <--- string to search
     +----+----+----+
```

If trailing part of c1 (accidentally) matches with c5, you may get incorrect result. I would suggest using unicode with unicode substring check function or multibyte substring check functions. ([_mbsstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz.aspx) for example)

Comment: Helpful answer ! What about strcmp ?

Comment: @virus721 `strcmp` is absolutely fine as long as 1. No character has byte 0 in it 2. Encoding of both strings is same.

Answer (score 2):

Modern systems use UTF-8 (or ASCII) as their multibyte encoding, where the use of this function is safe.

To be strictly conforming and make your code work even on old/exotic platforms, you need to take additional problems into account.

First, the good news: In every multibyte encoding, a 0-byte indicates the end of a string, regardless of state. This means, your `strstr` won’t cause a crash or something, but the result may be wrong.

As an example, consider UTF-7, a 7-bit clean way to encode Unicode. UTF-7 is a multibyte encoding having a *shift state*, which means how a byte is interpreted may depend on the context where it appears. E.g. (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7#Examples)) “£1AKM” is encoded as `+AKM-AKM` in UTF-7, where the `+` sign changes the state and the interpretation of letters like `A`. Doing `strstr(str, "AKM")` would match the first AKM portion (after the `+`), although this is part of the encoding of `£` and actually should match the `AKM` portion after the `-` (setting the shift state back to the initial state).

Comment: I forgot to precise that I use UTF-8 encoding, but thanks for the tips anyway.

Comment: *"UTF-8 (or ASCII) as their multibyte encoding"* -- ASCII is not a multibyte encoding. (It's also not the same as UTF-8.) ASCII covers only characters 0 through 127, each of which easily fits in a single byte.