# Is there any replacements for strstr in C/C++ that can be used with multibyte strings?

Tags: c++, c, internationalization

I am trying to do `strstr` in C++ with Shift-JIS strings. But since the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571622/is-it-safe-to-use-strstr-to-search-for-multibyte-utf-8-characters-in-a-string) states that there could be false positives if the standard `strstr` is used, I couldn't just use the regular one in the standard library. Apparently Windows provides `_mbsstr` that does what I want, but I am targeting other platforms as well.

I tried to use gnulib as it also provides `mbsstr` but I couldn't get it to work as it requires autotools, and I am using cmake.

Is there anything else that achieves it?

Comment: @PasserBy Can it be customized to handle OP's variable-length encoding?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Usually you prefer to convert from Shift-JIS to something like UCS-4, then search the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: unlike UTF-8, the [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) encoding causes false positives for `strstr` and `strchr` for single byte characters.

Here is a simplistic custom function for C:

```
#include <string.h>

char *sjis_strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    unsigned char c1, c2 = *s2++;
    if (c2 == '\0')
        return s1;
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    while ((c1 = *s1++) != '\0') {
        if (c1 == c2 && !strncmp(s1, s2, len2))
            return (char *)(s1 - 1);
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            break;
        s1 += (c1 >= 0x81 && c1 <= 0x9F) || (c1 >= 0xE0 && c1 <= 0xFC);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Isn't comparing `char` to anything larger than `0x7f` nonportable?

Comment: @PasserBy: you are absolutely correct! Answer amended using `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either write a custom Shift-JIS search algorithm or decode to a string suitable for regular search algorithms, e.g. UCS-4 or UTF-8.

For example, a naive custom algorithm based on [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) description of Shift-JIS

```cpp
using sjchar = std::uint8_t;
using sjstring_view = std::basic_string_view<sjchar>;

bool multibyte_prefix(sjstring_view str)
{
    auto first = str[0];
    if(first >= 0x81 && first <= 0x9f)
        return true;
    if(first >= 0xe0 && first <= 0xef)
        return true;
    return false;
}

size_t custom_search(sjstring_view str, sjstring_view sub)
{
    if(sub.empty())
        return 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size();)
    {
        if(str.substr(i).starts_with(sub))
            return i;
        if(multibyte_prefix(str))
            i += 2;
        else
            i++;
    }
    return str.npos;
}
```